# Google Sheets Index query for Multiple Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]Good afternoon,

I have a total of 5 Data entry sheets and need assistance on creating a master query that returns a consolidated list (from all Data entry sheets), more specifically a list of names who either received a 'No' or '0' or '1' on the Pre or Post assessment.

[Dummy Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tUGzNh6QP8sHJKxjnLpQtwbLjRShJhjv-z6dqJlOGrA/edit?usp=sharing)

```
Expected Result, in **Index** sheet:

**Standard:** (Data entry columns C4:BK4) 
**Student Name:** (Data entry column A) of those that have a 'No' in either the 'Pre' or 'Post' for each Standard (see: columns C4:AG4 on the 3-5h example).
**Pre:** Returns - No, 0 or 1 (from each Pre column in Data entry) 
**Post:** Returns - No, 0 or 1 (from each Pre column in Data entry) 
**Cross Cutting Concept:** (Data entry columns C4:BK5)
```

A previous query iteration returned all 'No' values from C8:AF="No" . On the Index sheet, columns T:BL shows an example of the initial query and result, but I would like to revise as indicated and consolidate into one master query.

```
=index(split(tocol(if('Kindergarten -  Data Entry'!C8:AF="No",scan(,'Kindergarten -  Data Entry'!C4:AF4,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c)))&"|"&'Kindergarten -  Data Entry'!A8:A,),1,1),"|"))


Data Entry Sheets:
Kindergarten -  Data Entry
1st Grade -  Data Entry
2nd Grade -  Data Entry
3rd Grade -  Data Entry
4th Grade -  Data Entry
5th Grade -  Data Entry
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Would you be fine with using Appscript?

Comment: @Serenity Yes I would be open to it, if that is the only option

Comment: Would you please provide an example of a successful result in the Index sheet. Even if just for one class.

Comment: I am confused that you appear to only want the "Student name" where there is a **No** in either the 'Pre' or 'Post' for each Standard; yet in the "Pre" and "Post" columns you want  to show "No or 0".  So, might a student not qualify for inclusion because they _do not_ have "No" but they _do_ have "0" in either the 'Pre' or 'Post'. Similarly, you want to show "1" but not "Yes"?

Comment: Sure - just to clarify, a Passing assessment value can be Either:
'Yes' (for Columns C8:AF) in Data Entry 
'2'   (for Columns AH8:BK) in Data Entry 

a Non-Passing assessment value can be Either:
'No' (for Columns C8:AF) in Data Entry 
'0' or '1'   (for Columns AH8:BK) in Data Entry

Comment: @rockinfreakshow final follow-up question , regarding the query you provided, I'm trying to add one column (Module #). It's located in each sheets 'A1' cell. I'm trying to add this column to the Index (column S). I've been attempting to revise your query but to no avail. Thanks again Dummy Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kSHBiDVCFMK4bEmCSZD9Yeh8xEhmF_um67BSegJy_D8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Added one solution here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tUGzNh6QP8sHJKxjnLpQtwbLjRShJhjv-z6dqJlOGrA/edit#gid=1623720231) for you to test out:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),tocol(A2:A,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Σ,index(match(,0/(indirect(c&"!A:A")<>""))),
 rep_,indirect(c&"!A8"):index(indirect(c&"!A:A"),Σ), grp_,hstack(indirect(c&"!C8"):index(indirect(c&"!AF:AF"),Σ),indirect(c&"!AH8"):index(indirect(c&"!BK:BK"),Σ)), header_,hstack(indirect(c&"!C4:AF4"),indirect(c&"!AH4:BK4")), header_2,hstack(indirect(c&"!C5:AF5"),indirect(c&"!AH5:BK5")), size_,2,
 Λ,reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(columns(grp_)/size_,1,1,size_),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,hstack(wrapcols(index(header_,c),rows(rep_),index(header_,c)),rep_,choosecols(grp_,sequence(size_,1,c)),wrapcols(index(header_2,c),rows(rep_),index(header_2,c)))))), 
 filter(Λ,regexmatch(index(Λ,,3)&"","No|1|0")+regexmatch(index(Λ,,4)&"","No|1|0"))))))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks again for your quick response on the query!

Comment: final follow-up question @rockinfreakshow , regarding the query you provided, I'm trying to add one column (Module #). It's located in each sheets 'A1' cell. I'm trying to add this column to the Index (column S). I've been attempting to revise your query but to no avail. Thanks again Dummy Sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kSHBiDVCFMK4bEmCSZD9Yeh8xEhmF_um67BSegJy_D8/edit#gid=1303047363